# jQuery find cells of a row not having class="hidden"

Tags: jquery, html

I need to find total number of columns inside a table.

I am able to get the total number of rows and total number of columns, but I need only those columns which are not hidden.

My HTML is like this.

```
<td data-group="general" data-id="edition1"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="edition2"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="edition3"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="studio1" class="hidden"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="studio2" class="hidden"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="studio3" class="hidden"></td>
<td data-group="general" data-id="studio4" class="hidden"></td>
```

jQuery

```
var table =  $('#ReportR > table')[0];
//Get number of rows/columns
var rowLength = table.rows.length;
var colLength = table.rows[0].cells.length;
```

But I need only those columns who dont have `class=hidden`.

Comment: You'll get more help if you post a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's not() method to filter your query:

```
$('td').not('.hidden')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLe243vL/

Answer (score 1):

`var colLength = $('#ReportR > table td:not(.hidden)').length();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:not()` selector

```
$(":not(.hidden)")
```

[See the documentation for more information.](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

you can target those element by doing something like this:

```
$('td:not(.hidden)')
```